# Spring: запуск теста под несколькими профилями

Tags: spring, юнит-тесты, junit

## Ситуация

В моём приложении два [профиля](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html): "production" и "dev". От профиля зависит, какая база данных используется.
Также есть тесты, проверяющие корректность считывания из БД. Хотелось бы, чтобы эти тесты проверялись на обоих базах данных.

## Вопрос

Существует ли способ сделать так, чтобы некоторые тесты прогонялись, как под профилем "production", так и под "dev"?

## Моё текущее решение

Лучшее, что я пока придумал — это писать [[@Test](/users/1155/test)](/users/1155/test)-методы в абстрактных классах и к каждому классу делать по annotation-only одной реализации на профиль. Но выглядит это весьма громоздко.

```
abstract class SomeDBTest {
    @Autowired SomeDBService database;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ... some code here
    }
}

@ActiveProfiles("production")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public class SomeDBProductionTest extends CommonDBTest {

}

@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public class SomeDBDevTest extends CommonDBTest {

}
```

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Обычно с девлоперского окружения нет доступа к продакшн окружению. И это правильно. Но если очень хочется, то правильнее будет просто запустить тесты дважды, с разными профилями, чем городить что-то непонятное в коде.

Comment: @a_gura согласен, результирующее желание мне самому кажется очень странным. Но юз-кейс вполне классический: я добавляю поле в таблицу на дев-окружении и хочу, чтобы тесты проверяли, не сломало ли это мои DAO-сервисы; выпуская апдейт, я делаю тоже самое с продакшн-базой для всех накопившихся изменений и также хочу проверки тестами.

Comment: @Jofsey основная мысль: запускайте тесты дважды - с одним профилем, потом с другим.

Comment: @Jofsey, вам нужны smoke-тесты на продакшене, которые не нужны на деве. И да, production пишется через u.